# I have some problems with the word "friendly"

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is a port which wants to provide convenient service in customs clearance, so I describe it as "a port friendly to customs clearance facilitation", which is a parody I make from the now ususal expression "environment-friendly something".

Is it a sensible expression or is there more concise expression for the same?

Comment: As a native speaker, I don’t have any problem with the use of _friendly_ in a context like that. I’d call it more a “spin-off” than a “parody,” though.

Comment: Or a mere "extension".

Comment: @LukeSawczak I do not really understand your reply, the word you gave is used as susbsitution for which word? Or please elaborate on it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this kind of thing is common in English.

> The district is **friendly** to young professionals looking to have a good time -- most establishments have no cover charge, and often have specials (special prices) on food and alcohol.
>
> Singapore is especially friendly to [expatriate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expatriate) businessmen since it has low income tax rates and no capital gains tax.

Actually, your phrase "friendly to customs clearance facilitation" sounds like a polite [euphemism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism), meaning the officials at the port are open to taking bribes in return for "forgetting" regulations or "losing" paperwork that might slow down the import process, or require the importer to pay government [tariffs](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tariff).

Comment: It is too bad if it has left such an impression on readers. Perhaps we can simply say "customs facilitation" without "clearance", since "clearance" has an emphasis on the result of the work, and "facilitation" more on the process?

Comment: @NanningYouth  Well, your intended meaning might be completely innocent, and I just have a naturally suspicious mind  :)

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew mentioned, "friendly" and "facilitate" aren't really the right words for a government agency that imposes taxes and tariffs; these could suggest that this port helps customers avoid certain taxes.

Some more suitable words could be: efficient, well-managed, convenient, or streamlined.  For example:

> a convenient port for efficient customs clearance